# How do I prevent "Your file was not found" message when deleting an image? Javascript

Tags: javascript

When I try to delete the image I get "Your file was not found" ,I'm using Google Chrome.

HTML:

```
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" id="upload_file" name="file" onchange="preview_image()" 
multiple/> 
</form>

<script>
function preview_image() 
{
 var total_file=document.getElementById("upload_file").files.length;
 for(var i=0;i<total_file;i++)
{
 $('#demo').append("<img id='pre' alt='image' 
 src='"+URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[i])+"'><br><button 
 id='del'>Delete</button><br>");
 }
 }

// Delete using jquery 
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on('click','button',function(event){
$(this).hide().prev().remove();
})
});
</script>
```

I have tried using Filereader. I know there is a method to use splice but was not able to come up with a solution. A chosen image comes up as preview, I would like the user to be able to delete an unwanted image using javascript or jquery.

Comment: `$("#pre").remove()` ?

Comment: $("#pre") removes all the images

Comment: Ok, you should append an id

Answer (score 1):

Use [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX) to delete your image with PHP using [unlink](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php), Javascript won't do that:

```
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" id="upload_file" name="file" onchange="preview_image()" 
multiple/> 
</form>

<script>
function preview_image() 
{
 var total_file=document.getElementById("upload_file").files.length;
 for(var i=0;i<total_file;i++)
{
 $('#demo').append("<img id='pre' alt='image' 
 src='"+URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[i])+"'><br><button 
 id='del' data-img='"+URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[i])+"'>Delete</button><br>");
 }
 }

// Delete using jquery 
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on('click','button',function(event){

$.post("yourcode.php", {img: $(this).data('img')}, function(data, status){
       if (data == '1'){
        alert("IMG DELETED");
        $(this).hide().prev().remove();
       } else {
          alert('ERROR DELETING IMAGE!');
       }
    });

})
});
</script>
```

Your code php:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['img'])){
  if (unlink($_POST['img'])) {
      echo json_encode('1'); //true
  } else {
      echo json_encode('0'); //false
  }
}
```

Comment: For some reason the code I posted works online but I got an Err message when working offline

Comment: Hmm... maybe cache? Turn off opcache in the php.ini file